# How to set a line coordinate for a symbolic line integral over a curve?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following closed curve, defined by a set of points.

```
points={{1., 0.00009}, {0.99754, 0.00189}, {0.9907, 0.00624}, {0.98037,
      0.0115}, {0.96698, 0.01741}, {0.95044, 0.02402}, {0.93064, 
      0.03188}, {0.90775, 0.04001}, {0.88202, 0.04848}, {0.8537, 
      0.05718}, {0.82309, 0.06616}, {0.79048, 0.07549}, {0.75616, 
      0.0851}, {0.72043, 0.09482}, {0.68359, 0.10446}, {0.64594, 
      0.11385}, {0.60778, 0.12287}, {0.56937, 0.13137}, {0.53099, 
      0.13916}, {0.49265, 0.14604}, {0.45435, 0.15177}, {0.41638, 
      0.15606}, {0.37887, 0.15868}, {0.34204, 0.15944}, {0.30609, 
      0.1582}, {0.2712, 0.15493}, {0.2376, 0.14964}, {0.20549, 
      0.14243}, {0.17504, 0.13344}, {0.14648, 0.12292}, {0.11999, 
      0.1111}, {0.09576, 0.09826}, {0.07395, 0.08459}, {0.05468, 
      0.0703}, {0.03811, 0.05576}, {0.02433, 0.04145}, {0.01338, 
      0.02769}, {0.00548, 0.01518}, {0.00098, 
      0.00518}, {0., -0.00021}, {0.00098, -0.00435}, {0.00548, -0.00787}, \
    {0.01338, -0.00871}, {0.02433, -0.00754}, {0.03811, -0.00539}, \
    {0.05468, -0.00292}, {0.07395, -0.00022}, {0.09576, 0.0027}, {0.11999,
       0.00584}, {0.14648, 0.00921}, {0.17504, 0.01279}, {0.20549, 
      0.01651}, {0.2376, 0.0203}, {0.2712, 0.0241}, {0.30609, 
      0.02786}, {0.34204, 0.03152}, {0.37887, 0.03503}, {0.41638, 
      0.03832}, {0.45435, 0.04134}, {0.49265, 0.044}, {0.53099, 
      0.04624}, {0.56937, 0.04801}, {0.60778, 0.04925}, {0.64594, 
      0.04992}, {0.68359, 0.04997}, {0.72043, 0.04936}, {0.75616, 
      0.04807}, {0.79048, 0.04608}, {0.82309, 0.04334}, {0.8537, 
      0.03978}, {0.88202, 0.03537}, {0.90775, 0.03013}, {0.93064, 
      0.02434}, {0.95044, 0.01851}, {0.96698, 0.0129}, {0.98037, 
      0.00756}, {0.9907, 0.00319}, {0.99754, 0.00068}, {1., -0.00003}};
closedcurve=RegionBoundary[Polygon[0.224 points]];
```

The points of the curve are defined in a Oxy Cartesian coordinate system. I would like to compute the line integral over this curve using a curvilinear coordinate *s* with origin in (0,0). In order to compute the indefinite line integral of this "sort":

```
Integrate[x[t], x\[Element]closedcurve,{t,0,t}]
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
BlacKow suggested to integrate this piece wise. This is how I've implemented the code:

```
int[i_, points_] := With[{},
  theta = 
   ArcTan[(points[[i + 1, 1]] - points[[i, 1]])/(points[[i + 1, 2]] - 
       points[[i, 2]])];
  x = points[[i, 1]] + s Sin[theta];
  Integrate[x, s]
  ]
Sum[int[i, p], {i, 1, Length[points] - 1}]
```

It seams to work. Yet I tried to test it with a general case, as follows:

```
pts = {{15 a, 8 a}, {0, 0}, {15 a, -8 a}, {9 a, 0}, {8 a, 0}};
Sum[int[i, pts], {i, 1, Length[pts] - 1}]
```

And apparently it returns "indeterminate". What could be wrong?

Comment: Well, you can change the coordinates to polar with     p=ToPolarCoordinates[points];
p[[All, {1, 2}]] = p[[All, {2, 1}]];

Comment: What does p[All,{1,2}]]=p[[All,{2,1}]]; mean?

Comment: Would you kindly explain how this would help?

Comment: For some reason, PolarListPlot demands $(\theta,r)$, so it swaps out the columns. I just did that to check it against plot of points.
You said you wanted to solve it in curvilinear coordinates, so the first step would be to chance to those, would it not?

Comment: I want the curvilinear coordinate system to be defined on my closed line (tangent and normal).

Comment: What about you figure out how to integrate over line segment - that will be simple linear  transformation and then sum up all integrals over all segments.

Comment: This is possibly a solution. Yet the difficulties I had trying to implement this were due to the fact that I would have to define coordinates for each segment, and this would be quite inefficient, in the sense that it would take ages. Yet this is what I do when I have a far smaller polygon. @BlacKow

Comment: @MirkoAveta if you can show what you get with one segment integration we will figure out the inefficiency.

Comment: The problem is that to define the coordinate system for each segment I would have to do a tremendous amount of work. This is what I meant with inefficiency. @BlacKow

Comment: @MirkoAveta No. If you figure out how to define your coordinate system once, Mathematica will do all segments for you. So create a function that takes two points and calculates the integral along the segment between these points. After that map this functions to all segments and sum up...

Comment: I've updated my question with the implemented function as you suggested. Yet still something questions me @BlacKow.

Answer (score 2):

For a closed curve you can parameterise it with the angular variable. First use $x=r cos(\theta),y=r sin(\theta)$ and then find $r=r(\theta)$ from the the curve. So you end up with $x=x(\theta),y=y(\theta)$.

First you change your coordinates to polar. Make sure to choose the origin inside the region or else you will not get a `[0,2Pi]` limit for the angle. I choose the centre of mass for that.

```
cen = Mean[points];
npts = Length[points]
pts1 = CoordinateTransform[{"Cartesian" -> "Polar", 2}, # - cen] & /@ points;
pts1 = pts1 /. {r_, q_} -> {q, r};

(*To avoid any jump in angular variable*)
tq = Abs@Differences[pts1[[All, 1]]];
jmp = Position[tq, Max[tq]][[1, 1]]

pts2 = Join[pts1[[jmp + 1 ;; npts]], pts1[[1 ;; jmp]]];

ListLinePlot[{pts2}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Since your line integral is $\int r(\theta) d \theta $, that is basically the area under the curve. You can use `Interpolation[pts2]` to get a functional form or simply do a numreical integration.

> Integrating line segment

Say you want to calculate distance from point 20 to point 30.

```
point1 = points[[20]]
point2 = points[[30]]
ListLinePlot[points, Epilog -> {Arrow[{cen, point1}], Arrow[{cen, point2}]}]
```

[image]

**Simple sum of norm**

```
Sum[Norm[points[[i + 1]] - points[[i]]], {i, 20, 30 - 1}]
```

0.357266

**Interpolation over Cartesian coordinates**

Here $dl = \sqrt{1+(dy/dx)^2} dx$

```
y[x_] = Interpolation[points[[20 ;; 30]]][x];
y1[x_] = D[f[x], x];
NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + y1[x]^2], {x, point1[[1]], point2[[1]]}]
```

-0.351545

**Interpolation over Polar coordinates**

Here $dl = \sqrt{r^2+(dr/dθ)^2} dθ$

```
θ1 = CoordinateTransform[{"Cartesian" -> "Polar", 2}, point1 - cen][[2]]
θ2 = CoordinateTransform[{"Cartesian" -> "Polar", 2}, point2 - cen][[2]]
θmin = θ1; θmax = θ2;
pts = Select[pts2, θmin < #[[1]] < θmax &];
r[θ_] = Interpolation[pts][θ];
r1[θ_] = D[r[θ], θ];
NIntegrate[ Sqrt[r[θ]^2 + r1[θ]^2], {θ, θmin, θmax}]
```

0.357266

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yet, I don't think this answers to my question. I don't want to integrate r. Instead, I would like to integrate x, that is the coordinate corresponding to the coordinate system of my set of points. Is it possible to solve this with the coordinate transformation you are suggesting?

Comment: For closed loop I think it is better to use cylindrical coordinate. You can easily find the limit in angular variable for any given `x` limit. Actually `theta` is your `t`.

Comment: Yet I still don't understand how I should transform also the argument of my integral.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my function that integrates $x$ over arbitrary segment defined by points $P_1$ and $P_2$:

```
r[p1_List, p2_List] := (p2*# + (1 - #) p1) &;
iSeg[p1_List, p2_List] := Module[{rr, v, x},
   rr[t_] := r[p1, p2]@t;
   v[t_] := Evaluate@Norm@D[rr[t], t];
   x[t_] := rr[t][[1]];
   Integrate[x[t] v[t], {t, 0, 1}]
   ];
iSeg[{0, 0}, {1, 0}] (* 1/2 *)

Total[iSeg @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] &@points] (* gives sum of all integrals *)
```

Here `v` is velocity i.e the element of length $ds=v dt$. You are integrating over $ds$ but after you used parametrization your $(x,y)$ became $(x(t),y(t))$ and your element of length $(ds)^2=(dx)^2+(dy)^2=(v_x^2+v_y^2)(dt)^2$

See some explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral).

For better understanding it can be useful to inspect several particular cases of line segment. Consider line segment parallel to X axis:

```
iSeg[{x1, A}, {x2, A}] // 
  FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> {x2 > x1}] & // Expand
(* -(x1^2/2) + x2^2/2 *)
```

In this case the linear integral corresponds to "normal" integral  $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \! x \, \mathrm{d}x$

Now consider line segment parallel to Y axis:

```
iSeg[{A, y1}, {A, y2}] // FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> {y2 > y1}] &
(* A (-y1 + y2) *)
```

In this case with $x$ being constant our integral becomes proportional to segment length.

Comment: BlacKow why is this integrating also on v? and what exactly is v?

Comment: @MirkoAveta see my edit

Comment: I think there has been a little misunderstanding. Actually t is not intended to mean time. I simply named t the coordinate defined on the closed line. @BlacKow.

Comment: @MirkoAveta `t` is parameter from curve parametrization. You can name it anything. When you calculate your integral you need to calculate absolute value of derivative: $|r'|$ ... It's convenient to think about $t$ as of time and about that derivative as of velocity. Read carefully the link i posted.

Comment: @MirkoAveta Also try to integrate over a segment that lies on X axis. See if you understand why it gets 1/2 in `iSeg[{0, 0}, {1, 0}]`

Comment: Lets see if this works with an example. Something still doesn't sound right. If I use as a set of points the following: pts = {{15 a, 8 a}, {0, 0}, {15 a, -8 a}, {9 a, 0}, {8 a, 0}, {15 a, 8 a}} . And name in order these points {1,2,3,4}. We may find that the integral of segment 4-1, should be off, by hand, 2t^2 /5. Instead with your code I would get, 30 a (3 t + t^2) Abs[a]. There is still something wrong in this, I think.

Comment: I don;t understand how you get `t` in your answer if your points depend on `a` only. Give me an example of **one** segment with numbers that you think it calculates incorrectly.

Comment: Yes. I've forgot to tell you that I changed one line of your code. I asked for a indefinite integral. This is why t shows up. Anyhow segment 4-1 IMHO is wrong. @BlacKow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40674/discussion-between-mirko-aveta-and-blackow).

Comment: @MirkoAveta now it's really confusing... What is an indefinite linear integral? There is no such thing! You integrate along a curve that has a start and end (if it's closed you can pick any point to be a start/end). Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?